# How to calculate quantity of vowels in segmented text?

Tags: python

I try to solve the task on Python where program shall segment inputed text by spaces (`' '` symbols), calculate all vowels in each segment and compare if quantities of vowels in each segment are equal.
Sample of my code is:

```
a=input('Input your text: ')
b=a.split(' ')       #problematic line
count = 0
vowels = set("aeiou")
for letter in a:
    if letter in vowels:
        count += 1
print("Quantity of vowels are:")
print(count)
```

When I input text `'la-lala-la la-lalala-la'`:

1. if code breaks in second line the result of running will be this one: [la-lala-la], [la-lalala-la];
2. code without second line calculates all vowels of the line without segmentation.

How to modify this code to compare quantity of vowels in each segment of line: [la-lala-la], [la-lalala-la]?

Comment: What exactly would be your expected output?

Comment: 1. Calculate vowels in each segment (in my sample 4 and 5);
2. 4 != 5 -> print message "no rhyme"

Answer (score 0):

The given code separates the input into a list of words, which is correct, but then incorrectly proceeds to count the vowels of the entire input. Instead, it should iterate over the list of words and count the vowels for each word individually.

From the nature of this question I assume, that you are a beginner and could use a more detailed explanation.

I would recommend making the vowel counting reusable by moving the related code into a new function named `count_vowels`. It is also good practice to use constants for things that don't change, like the set of vowels. This makes the code more readable. In python this is done by writing the variable name in capital letters. (Notice I added `letter.lower()` so that vowels written as the capital letter are counted as well.)

Now we can loop over the words using the new function inside the loop to count. We output the count and save it to a list as well. (Notice I renamed the variables `a` to `user_input` and `b` to `words` for better readability.)

I assume by comparing the quantity of vowels you mean to check, if all counts are equal. This can be done by using the build in [all](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_all.asp) function. It returns true, if all items of the argument are true. And as the argument, we create a list containing true or false for each count, depending on whether it is equal to the first count. To do this, we can use the [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) expression `[count == counts[0] for count in counts]`.

This is the resulting program:

```py
VOWELS = set("aeiou")

def count_vowels(s):
    count = 0
    for letter in s:
        if letter.lower() in VOWELS:
            count += 1
    return count

user_input = input('Input your text: ')
words = user_input.split(' ')
counts = []
for word in words:
    count = count_vowels(word)
    counts += [count]
    print("Vowels in " + word + ": " + str(count))

if all([count == counts[0] for count in counts]):
    print("All counts are equal. Rhyme.")
else:
    print("Not all counts are equal. No rhyme.")
```

It creates this output:

```
Input your text: la-lala-la la-lalala-la
Vowels in la-lala-la: 4
Vowels in la-lalala-la: 5
Not all counts are equal. No rhyme.
```

As a side note: Although it is not the topic of this website, the count of vowels in two words does not determine whether they rhyme or not.

Comment: That's fantastic, thanks a lot! :) Yes, I'm intern of Python and now test different tasks to improve my skills. This task seems quite interesting for me and I decided to consult with more experienced guys who use code on practice. 

And how can I compare the results of output? 

We output "str" meaning, but need to convert it in "int" and compare all the results between each other.
In this sample the idea is following: 4 != 5 -> print message "no rhyme"